# jQuery - Choosing a variable based on the ID of the element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm probably overlooking a more obvious way to do what I want, but...

I have a list of JS variables with names that are identical to the ID's of some elements on my page. When I click one of the elmeents, I want to be able to use the clicked element's ID to determine which variable should be used in my function. My variable names correspond to my element ID's - there must be some way to take the value of my clicked element's ID using `$(this).id` and then find the variable that matches that string? Just to be clear, the content of the variables is not at all related to the variable names or element ID's - the variables are set when the page loads and I'd like to avoid setting them every time the function is run! And I know I could probably use `onclick` for this, but I'm trying to avoid that because apparently it's inferior now?!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you storing this "list" as an `object` so that you can look up the values by key? Try showing some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to make an array with al of your ids names

```
thisArray = {
    uniqueID1: 'Your value for uniqueID1',
    uniqueID2: 'Your value for uniqueID2'
};
```

you can call an element by a class for example

## HTML:

```
<div id="uniqueID1" class="elements_class"> Div Content </div>
<div id="uniqueID2" class="elements_class"> Div Content </div>
```

## jQuery:

```
$('div.elements_class').click(function(){
    var now_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(thisArray[now_id]);
});
```

Comment: [`Array`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) should not have index names...

Comment: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/ Use an Object instead of Array.

Comment: You should use Object() instead of Array()

Comment: just like that? just replace Array() with Object() is the same thing?

Comment: @Memolition - You can say that. They are similar.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Although you're right to suggest `Object` should be used, `Array` is also `Object` :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you want is to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$(el).data('myobject', {
    x: 123,
    y: 456
});
```

Then to retrieve:

```
$(el).on('click', function() {
    var obj = $(this).data('myobject');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an object to store the variables you are talking about with key/value pairings, you can just call `variableObject[this.id]` to get that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think of storing them in an object?

Example :

```
var obj = {
   'id1' : value1,
   'id2' : value 2,
   //...
}
```

Then you can acces them like that

```
obj[this.id]
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` is basically `this.id` :)

Comment: Probly, never used it actually. Thank for the info, updating my answer!